# Chrome Extension - content_script.js not loading properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to learn how to use the `content_script.js` to send a request to the background page of my chrome extension.  I have read many SO answers about this, but none have helped me.  I cannot seem to get the listener to execute.

**Manifest.json**

```
"background_page": "background.html",
...
"content_scripts":[ 
{
"matches": ["http://*/*"],
"run_at": "document_start",
"js": ["jquery.min.js", "content_script.js"]  
}
]
...
```

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({'url': 'http://example.com'}, function(data) {
    $("#list").html(data);
});
```

**background.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: request.url,
        username: "username",
        password: "password",
        success: callback
    }); 
});

</script>
```

Do I need to inject the content_script.js anywhere?  From my understanding, this should all run in the background when the extension loads.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see content script getting injected, check dev tools console - script section

Comment: No, it's not getting injected.

Comment: What is the website you are testing on, make sure its not SSL

Comment: Do you have permission to fetch data from `http://example.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Because of `"run_at": "document_start"`, DOM is not ready when you inject this script, so you can't do `$("#list").html(data);`.

Either remove that line from the manifest or put your code inside `window.onload` listener.

Comment: So, removing the `run_at` will force the script to inject when the extension is loaded?  Is there no place I have to specify when/where the script is injected?

Comment: @rybo Not when the extension is loaded but when the page you are injecting into is loaded, so you can search the DOM. I didn't understand second part of the question. What do you mean by when/where?